# Why not javascript producing output of the function?

Tags: javascript

Why not javascript producing output of the function?

```
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
var weight = prompt("what is your weight?");
function check(name ,weight){
       if (weight> 25) {
           alert (name + "Your weight is " + weight + "which is not normal."+ "Sorry");
       }
       else {
           alert (name + "Your weight is " + weight + "which is normal." + "Welcome");
       }

    return check;
}check;
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Because you have a syntax error. 2. Because you aren’t calling the function you defined.

Comment: you dont seem to be calling check. also your function is not closed

Comment: Please check again, EDITED

Comment: You have to passthrough the parameters `check(name, weight);`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's malformed, you don't even end the function.

you have to return a value in order for it to return anything.

Maybe this is what you want to achieve:

```
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
var weight = prompt("what is your weight?");

function check(name ,weight){
  if (weight> 25) {
     return name + "Your weight is " + weight + "which is not normal."+ "Sorry";
  } else {
     return name + "Your weight is " + weight + "which is normal." + "Welcome";
  }
}

alert(check(name, weight));
```

Notice how I pass the arguments `name` and `weight` into the `check`-function

Answer (score 1):

**It should be like this:**

```
       var name = prompt("What is your name?");
       var weight = prompt("what is your weight?");

       function check(name ,weight){
           if (weight> 25) {
               alert (name + "Your weight is " + weight + "which is not normal."+ "Sorry");
           }
           else {
               alert (name + "Your weight is " + weight + "which is normal." + "Welcome");
           }
        return true;               // check is invalid
       }                           // you forgot to close it
       check(name,weight);          // calling the function
```

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a function, you are declaring parameters: name and weight. These parameters only can be used inside the scope of that function. It looks like you are trying to set them outside the scope. Then you are returning variable check. Which is empty. Also you're not calling your function from outside your function, so function check() never will be triggered.

Here an example ([live example](http://jsfiddle.net/aum07c6b/)):

```
var input1="peter"; input2=10;
check(input1, input2);
function check(name, weight) {
    var check;
    if (weight < 25) { //true
        check = "Text"+name;
    } else {
        check = "No text"+name;
    }
    return alert(check);
}
```

PS: didn't tested this code yet.

Comment: `return alert(...);` makes less sense, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The function needs a external invoke to perform the action. So if you want to display the result you can do in the above manner add

```
   function check(name ,weight){
       if (weight> 25) {
           alert (name + "Your weight is " + weight + "which is not normal."+ "Sorry");
       }
       else {
           alert (name + "Your weight is " + weight + "which is normal." + "Welcome");
       }
       return true;               
   }

   check(name,weight);
```

or you can invoke it by other way

```
<p id="print"></p>
<script>
    function check(name ,weight){
        if (weight> 25) {
           alert (name + "Your weight is " + weight + "which is not normal."+ "Sorry");
        }
        else {
           alert (name + "Your weight is " + weight + "which is normal." + "Welcome");
        }
        return check;               
    }                 

    var name = prompt("What is your name?");
    var weight = prompt("what is your weight?");

    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = check(name, weight);
</script>
```